# How do I add a value to a cell in Excel if it's an int?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel table with some cells that are numbers and some cells that are strings. I want a function that can add search through the table, and if the cell is a number, add it(+) and if it's a string, ignore it.

I know how to do this easily in say C# but how do I do this in Excel?

This is what I want the equivelant of:

```
object[] celldata = new object[] {"blabla",2,3,"blabla",3,"blabla"}

int additioncell;

foreach(object cells in celldata)
{
    if(cells.Equals(int)
    additionalcell += (int) cells;
}
```

How do I convert this into an Excel function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sum()` function should work. It will ignore the strings.

Additionally, you can use `isnumber()` and `istext()` to check if a cell is a number or text.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the cells in question and create a custom format.[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that formatting this way, in general, may affect cell values in VBA. If I were to make a custom type like `"derp"@`, then my `Range(Address).Value` would look at the unformatted value. To get the formatted value, you would use `Range(Address).Text`.